# How can I connect via peerjs without a browser?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, webrtc, peerjs

My question is about whether I can connect to peerjs without a browser.
So if or how I can create a WebRtc video and data peer to peer connection between a device that send
and a device that can see the video through the browser.

So far I have a well working WebRtc connection from one browser to the other.
I have a website using NodeJS, a peerjs server as well as a stun and turn server running and I connect using the peerjs api
using the javascript code that is executed in the browser.

However, I would like to connect on one side without a browser, for example to make it more efficient on a Raspberry pi.

I found this example which provides a python port for peerjs, but it is very hard to understand and poorly documented.

https://github.com/ambianic/peerjs-python

I was able to connect to my peerjs server with this. Now I can't get any further.

I would appreciate any suggestions to solve this problem or any other ideas or examples to establish a connection using peerjs without a browser. Maybe with c++ or Nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a native WebRTC library like [libdatachannel](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel). The examples show how to connect browsers to native clients, and you might adapt them to be compatible with the PeerJS signaling protocol. It features a C and C++ API but there is also a [Node.js wrapper](https://github.com/murat-dogan/node-datachannel).